# Merging pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

I have two dfs, one called master:

```
     ARI     Flesch    Kincaid      time  VIX_close  FEDFUNDS  \
15.219540  40.099442  14.969857  01/02/08  26.128000  4.220000   
19.154130  38.308678  16.955482  01/02/08  26.128000  4.220000   
17.859696  35.896056  15.457418  01/02/13  13.446333  0.158667

 Baseline_overall_index  News_Based_Policy_Uncert_Index  
             110.973189                      120.994318  
             110.973189                      120.994318  
             190.472390                      213.912415
```

the second is called data:

```
     ARI     Flesch    Kincaid                 Speaker     Score  \
19.285543  26.507396  17.649118             Minutes FRC -1.697248   
15.010289  42.676816  13.966083  J. Alfred Broaddus Jr.  0.403775   
15.009436  42.707457  13.961809                     NaN  0.312579

    time
02/04/16
08/16/16
09/28/16
```

I would like to merge the dfs on 'time' which is a datetime object. Also, individual days are missing from data df, while all days are filled in master though both dfs may have duplicate entries per individual day.

Running the code below I get the following output:

Code:

```
remix = pd.merge(master, data)
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ARI, Flesch, Kincaid, time, VIX_close, FEDFUNDS, 
Baseline_overall_index, News_Based_Policy_Uncert_Index, Speaker, 
Score, Residual, Date]
Index: []
```

Comment: try this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: "Running the code below I get the following output ... " but you've only showed us the one line of code.  Please include the unabridged code that fails.

Comment: Its difficult to comment on your entire data without looking at it but the data you have provided have not common dates and hence the merge on date will return an empty dataframe

Comment: you have to tell pandas on which column or index to merge. if `ARI` is the index, it tries to merge on that one at the moment, but since there are no corresponding entries, the merged DataFrame is empty